# WildFly 8 patching

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

With all the hype on WildFly, we were really looking forward to it. There remains one questions though. I can find a lot of information on patching and how to apply a patch, but where do you actually get the patch from?

Is it only for EAP customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general patching is not solely for EAP customers, however there are no patches available for WFLY at the moment. We do plan on providing them in future though. Once they are released they will show up on the downloads page: http://wildfly.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

No it is not EAP only feature.
To be fair code was first developed for WildFly and later backported to EAP.

Plan is to provide patches for future releases, for example you will be able to go from 8.1.0.Final to 8.0.0.Final just with a patch.